# How to wait for the first command but not the second, where the two are joined by the && operator

Tags: bash, command-line

I have a bash `for` loop like this:

```bash
for file in *.mp4; do
  command1 "${file}" && command2 "${file}"
done
```

This makes `command2` to run whenever `command1` is successful, which is expected.

Now what I want is for the loop to **wait only for `command1` to finish** , but **no need to wait for `command2`** to finish before iterating. Is there a way to do this?

What I've tried, but did not work:

- `command1 && command2 &` - does not wait for `command1` to exit, runs parallel
- `command1 && ( command2 & )` - waits for `command2` to exit, no need

Comment: Also: option 1 works like you want it too on zsh: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88235/70524

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bit more verbose, but this should work:

```
for file in *.mp4; do
  if command1 "${file}"; then
    command2 "${file}" &
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I like [the answer of @muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/762564/105126) and accepted it as the main answer.

Also found a similar way and I'm posting it here as an alternative:

```bash
for file in *.mp4; do
  command1 "${file}"
  [ "${?}" -eq 0 ] && command2 "${file}" &
done
```

Comment: What benefit do you see in spawning an extra process to evaluate the result that the `if` above gave you at no cost?